# Laravel(Lumen) unique validation rule for an array data when updating

Tags: laravel, validation, lumen-5.4

I am trying to add a unique rule on an array of data and wants to ignore the unique rule to a given id when updating the same record.

When creating a new record I am using rules like

```
$rules = [
            'provider.*.link' => 'required|url|unique:providers,link',
        ];
```

and my data array looks like

```
 [provider] => [
                [0] =>[
                       [link] => http://mysite.local/1
                [1] =>[
                       [link] => http://mysite.local/1
              ]
```

which works fine. But, when updating same data I can't figure it out how to ignore unique rule to their respective ids.

I know how to do it when there's no array like

```
'link' => 'required|url|unique:providers,link,' . $id,
```

but not sure how to use it when data is an array.

My update data array looks like

```
 [provider] => 
        [
            [0] =>
                [
                    [id] => 3
                    [link] => http://mysite.local/1
                ]

            [1] =>
                [
                    [id] => 4
                    [link] => http://mysite.local/1
                ]

        ]
```

I am using Lumen and using the same function for creating and updating records. 
Is there's a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$rules = [
    ....
];

$providers = request('provider');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($providers); $i++) {
    $rules['provider.' . $i . '.link'] = 'required|url|unique:providers,link,' . $providers[$i]['id'];
}

return $rules;
```